# Calculating angle of line crossing two points - how to scale correctly?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two points and would like to calculate the angle of the line crossing these points in degrees.

I calculated the angle like so:

```
import numpy as np

p1 = [0, 0.004583285714285714]
p2 = [1, 0.004588714285714285]

x1 = p1[0]
y1 = p1[1]

x2 = p2[0]
y2 = p2[1]

angle = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y1 - y2, x2 - x1))

print(angle)
```

As expected, the angle is a very small negative number (a small downward slope in relation to the X plane):

`-0.00031103423163937605`

If I plot this, you will see what I mean:

```
plt.ylim([0,1])  # making y axis range the same as X (a full unit)
plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2])
```

[image]

Clearly the angle of that line is a very small number because the Y values are so small.

I know the lowest y number in this plot is `0.00458` and the highest is `0.00459`.

I'm having trouble coming up with the way to scale this properly so that I can obtain this angle instead:

[image]

Which is closer to -35 degrees or so (visually).

How can I get the angle a person would see if the chart was plotted with the Y axis ranging only between those min and max values above?

Of course all plots are just for illustration - I'm trying to calculate just the raw angle number given two points and the min and max values for the Y axis.

Comment: Why would the angle change as the scale of the chart changes? Can you share a diagram to precisely describe what you're looking for?

Comment: What plot? There is no code for any plot. You can't scale a dimensionless number like this, but you could just round it up to `0.00455`. You've not given any detail, though

Comment: Sorry, I realize this is not clear. I will update the question, thanks!

Comment: The angle of the line in the plot will depend on the ratio of the plot x and y axes. If the ratio is 1.0 (e.g. 10 pixels/unit of x and 10 pixels/unit of y) then the line will be at the angle you calculated using the x and y values. For other ratios the angle will be different, of course.

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated the question to make it more clear. Essentially, knowing the min and max values for the Y axis, I'd like to get the line that crosses the points if they were to be plotted with such Y axis. Does it make sense?

Comment: Only your perception of the angle changes, because you have different scales. At some point you seem to have switched y1 and y2, because for the numbers give in the first code block, the graph should show a positive angle (y2 is bigger than y1). Also you would get a positive angle, when you would take `np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)`. To calculate the scale from a "perceived angle" of 45 degrees you just need to scale y against x such that the scaled difference in the ys is the same as the scaled difference in x. If  the x are unscaled, the y need a 'zoom' of 1 over the difference in the y.

Comment: "How can I get the angle a person would see if the chart was plotted with the Y axis ranging only between those min and max values above?" I assume, you want both the `xlim` and the `ylim` to be given by the points? Then the "perceived angle" still depends on the lengths of the x- and y-axis. Are yo sure that this is what you want?

Comment: @PaulG. I have the y limits, and the points. I just need the angle. So in this case instead of printing that minuscule negative number, it should be closer to -35. That scaling is the part I'm having an issue with.

Comment: But this angle has nothing to do with geometry (as in geometry in a Euclidean 2D plane). And as I said if you change the aspect ratio of your plot this angle will change again. Geometry only makes sense with your axes having the same scale.

Comment: So to answer your question you have to give not only the points and the `ylim`, but also the `xlim` and the length ratio between the axes.

Comment: I understand... the X values are always 0 and 1. I understand you're saying I need to scale the Y axis.. this is precisely what I'm having issues with.

Essentially, I have the min and max value for the Y axis, I know x1 is always 0 and x2 is always 1, and I know the y values (that fall between the y min and max values). 

The plot above can take this info and plot that line, which has an angle relative to the X plane of more or less -35 degrees. I am just trying to input the same info I gave to plot, and get -35 as an output. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I solved and posted an answer in case anyone is curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, turns out was exceedingly simple and I'm not sure why I was having trouble with it (or why folks seem not to understand the question ¯\ *(ツ)*/¯ ).

The angle I was looking for can be obtained by

```
yRange = yMaxValue - yMininumValue
scaledY1 = y1 / yRange
scaledY2 = y2 / yRange

angle = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(scaledY1 - scaledY2, x2 - x1))
```

Which for the values posted in the question, result in `-28.495638618242538`